# Check string contains special characters in batch skript

Tags: batch-file

Need to verify if absolute path contains special characters in batch script and set value false or true. I have set of symbols to be verified !@#$%^&"№;

I tried this:

```
SET containsSpecial=false
SET specialCharacters=%%,#,!,^^^&,@,$,^^^^,~
echo %specialCharacters%
FOR %%i IN (%specialCharacters%) DO (if NOT "%cd%"=="%cd:%%i=%" SET containsSpecial=true)
echo %containsSpecial%
pause
```

In perspective it shoud write smth like: "Your absolute path invalid and contains:{set of special characters located in path}"

Comment: You would need to use [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) like `!cd:%%i=!` to ensure that `%%i` is expanded before the [sub-string replacement](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) expression, but then you would still not be able to check for `!` (recognised by delayed expansion) and `~` (interpreted as [sub-string expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html))...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution with pattern:

```
Echo "%cd%"|findstr /R "[%%#^&^^^^@^$~!]" 1>nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    Echo Invalid path: "%cd%"
    Echo Remove special symbols: "%#&^@$~!"
)
```

Comment: Your string of characters is quoted, so there is no need for any caret escapes. You can simply use `findstr /R "%%#&^@$~!"`. Or you could use `findstr /L "%% # & ^ @ $ ~ !"`. I find the literal search easier to read.

Comment: Also, I prefer conditional command concatenation over use of ERRORLEVEL - `findstr /L "%% # & ^ @ $ ~ !" >nul && (success commands here)`